# How to losslessly replace a specific area in a range of frames

Tags: editing, windows

I have a short screen recording of an old video game (duration 1:38.72, 2468 frames, 25 fps, 320×200 px, 4 colours only, bgr24, CamStudio Lossless Codec, no sound, AVI).

The video contains an incorrect area (static, 16×16 px, top left corner at [136, 144]) in a range of frames (starting at 0:43.88 and ending at 1:38.44).

I'd like to replace that area in that range with correct data, everything losslessly.

I searched for "replace area in range of frames" on this server but didn't find anything.

Would you know how to do that with free software on Windows please? Maybe FFmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if FFmpeg supports the Camstudio Lossless Codec, but if it would. Then replacing the area with a PNG file (hence: adding a logo) could be a solution.

The explanation is done here at "Timing the overlay".
https://superuser.com/questions/683643/how-to-add-my-logo-for-the-first-30-seconds-in-a-video-with-ffmpeg

In that example codec:a copy was already given (for audio). If you would take any lossless videocodec the result will be lossless.

Comment: I'm surprised the overlay filter processing does not take place at RGB or YUV444. Great catch.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to overlays, Skinkie!

I've checked Low power's answer at [ffmpeg - how to apply filters without losing quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435420/ffmpeg-how-to-apply-filters-without-losing-quality) and [overlays](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-overlay-1) in FFmpeg documentation.

The command that will do the magic is:

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i input.avi -i patch.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=136:144:enable=between(t\,43.88\,98.44):format=auto" -f yuv4mpegpipe -pix_fmt yuv444p output.y4m`

Comment: OK, it's not exactly lossless because the color space conversion from bgr24 to yuv444 alters the colors slightly. But I still internally consider it lossless because no artifacts are introduced and the output still has exactly 4 colors. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/edit) to do this.
It is free, runs on windows, and [has great object removal tools](https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/make-objects-disappear-davinci-resolve/).